# Incomplete types in return-type and parameters of a function declared but not defined

Tags: c, function, language-lawyer, declaration, incomplete-type

Is the following code valid C? ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/aqc3hd))

```c
typedef struct none none;
none f(none, none);
```

To be clear: the identifier `f` never appears in the translation unit
again and the function itself is never defined, not even in another
translation unit.

Comment: Have you tried to compile it? (If compiled - valid, otherwise - not valid)

Comment: @sergeyrar I'm not asking about whether specific compilers accept the code as is. Some do, some don't. I'm asking whether it's valid from the standard's point of view. Notice the `language-lawyer` tag.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which compilers do and don't accept it?  Are you sure they are all intending to comply to the same standard?  I haven't yet found any that don't accept it.

Comment: @NateEldredge gcc, clang and others accept the code. cparser ([git](https://pp.ipd.kit.edu/git/cparser), not on godbolt) doesn't accept it. It complains about the incomplete type as parameter: cparser: "error: anonymous 'parameter' has incomplete type".

Comment: Interesting: GCC 10,2.0 running on RHEL 7.4 accepts the code, even with options `gcc -pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c18 …`.  If you tried to use or implement the function in the source file, then the error is correct — and GCC spots it.  I think there's room to argue that `cparser` is correct and GCC has an oversight.  I'm not sure a conforming program could spot the problem though — it isn't conforming code if it won't compile in a conforming compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C17 standard says explicitly that parameters are allowed to have incomplete types:

> (6.7.6.3 (12)) If the function declarator is not part of a definition of that function, parameters may have incomplete
> type and may use the `[*]` notation in their sequences of declarator specifiers to specify variable
> length array types.

So cparser is wrong to reject the code on that basis.

As for return types, there doesn't seem to be a clear statement either way.  [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration) says "The return type of the function [...] must be a **complete** non-array object type or the type void" but I can't find a corresponding requirement in the standard.  The standard does say in 6.9.1 (3) under "Function definitions" that "the return type of a function shall be `void` or a complete object type other than array type", but I read that as referring to definitions only.  Likewise, 6.5.2.2(1) requires that a function being called must have a complete return type or `void`.

So my opinion would be that incomplete return types are allowed in declarations, so long as the function is not defined or called.  But it's hard to be certain.

Comment: "[...] 6.9.1 (3) [...] but I read that as referring to definitions only." That's how I've read it as well, but then the validity of the code hinges on another unknown for me: does a function declaration need an eventual definition (possibly in another TU) or not?

Comment: @nebel: I think not.  The function `f` is declared with external linkage, and 6.9(5) says "If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an expression
(other than as part of the operand of a sizeof or _Alignof operator whose result is an integer
constant), somewhere in the entire program there shall be exactly one external definition for the
identifier; otherwise, there shall be no more than one."  Here we are in the "otherwise" case, so zero definitions is allowed.